# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame==2.0.0.dev10

Tags: python

I need help with this error, tried downgrading and changing the version of python but can't seem to fix it. I need it to be this exact version of `pygame==2.0.0.dev10`

Comment: That version is not available on pypi: https://pypi.org/project/pygame/#history

Comment: Check this link. It may help you :https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/1953 . Especially this response: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/1953#issuecomment-644900574